# gunicorn works when called with docker-compose run but not docker-compose up

Tags: python, flask, docker-compose, gunicorn

I am trying to start a flask app in a docker-compose. When I run it as follows:

```
docker-compose run web /usr/local/bin/gunicorn restml.app:app -b :8000
```

`gunicorn` starts fine but when I add the following line to by `docker-compose.yml`

```
command: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn restml.app:app -b :8000 --error-logfile - --log-level DEBUG
```

I get

```
web_1    | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 557, in spawn_worker
web_1    |     worker.init_process()
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 126, in init_process
web_1    |     self.load_wsgi()
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 136, in load_wsgi
web_1    |     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
web_1    |     self.callable = self.load()
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
web_1    |     return self.load_wsgiapp()
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
web_1    |     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 357, in import_app
web_1    |     __import__(module)
web_1    | ImportError: No module named 'restml'
```

The file structure is:

```
web
|-> Dockerfile
|-> requirements.txt
\-> restml
    \->app.py
```

My `app.py` is

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Index Page'


@app.route('/hello')
def hello():
    return 'Hello, World'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

The `web` entry of my `docker-compose.yml` is

```
web:
  build: ./web
  expose:
    - "8000"
  volumes:
    - /usr/src/app/
  env_file: .env
  environment:
     FLASK_DEBUG: 'true'
  command: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn restml.app:app -b :8000 --error-logfile - --log-level DEBUG
```

When I do

```
docker-compose run web
```

I get

```
[2016-10-20 17:20:22 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.6.0
[2016-10-20 17:20:22 +0000] [1] [DEBUG] Arbiter booted
[2016-10-20 17:20:22 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (1)
[2016-10-20 17:20:22 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2016-10-20 17:20:22 +0000] [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
[2016-10-20 17:20:22 +0000] [1] [DEBUG] 1 workers
```

So it seems to be more `docker-compose` related than anything else.

Can someone explain how I could fix this?

## Additional info

When I run `docker-compose run web ls` I see,

```
Dockerfile  requirements.txt  restml
```

and when I run `docker-compose run web ls restml` I see,

```
app.py
```

All files are mode 0644 and files 0755.

Comment: If you rename app.py to \_\_init\_\_.py do you get the same error?

Comment: Just renamed it and same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some dead containers were still running in the background. I removed all of them restarted and everything works now.

I removed them using,

```
docker ps --all |  grep restml | cut -c138- | xargs docker rm
```